# Targeting the same spell on stack

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [Grapeshot](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrapeshot%5d) and my oponnent plays [Negate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNegate%5d), can I play a [Remand](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRemand%5d) on Grapeshot to send it back to my hand?

Comment: What makes you think there might be a problem with doing this?

Comment: This is Grapeshot - you might want to remand it ANYWAY just so you can play it again, since your storm count is now going to be 2 more than it was before!

Comment: @corsiKa Three, even, thanks to the enemy counterspell counting as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is fine.

Remand will counter Grapshot and move it to its owner's hand. Then, when it comes time for Negate to resolve, it will be countered by the rules instead (for not having any legal targets).

It's worth noting that Negate is particularly ineffective against Grapeshot as it will not stop the copies from being made even if it counters the original spell.